# PB App works only old SQL Server but not on the new. CONFUSED

Tags: powerbuilder, powerbuilder-build-deploy, powerbuilder-2017

I wrote a system in Powerbulder 6.0 a while back (mid 2000's) and it was working with MSSQL Server 2008 on a Windows Server 2008R2 up to now (and is still working). It was connecting via ODBC. The system logged into a DB via a DB user name, then that user name was looked up in custom tables and read permissions for the application (all permissions were defined in custom tables and have nothing to do with DB permissions). Again, these permissions are read by code.
I needed to move to a different server.

New Server:
Microsoft Server 2016R3
MSSql Server 2017

The same application logs into the old DB and is able to have the right custom (code defined) permissions.
However, when logging into the new DB (exactly replicated from the old) - the same application does not read the custom permissions for the user (though it does log into the DB successfully).

This is really puzzling. I dont have source code :(.
Any ideas?

Thank you,
Michael Feldman

Comment: We had an issue where a database was replicated. The user names were the same, but their security ids were different. (I think that's what happened). You may need to double check the permissions on the new database to make sure they are the same.

Comment: It allows me to login into the DB, its the reading of the data that is what screwing it up.  I just read that *= (outer join) in the SQL join is no longer supported in new SQL Servers. I think that is the issue. In this case I am in trouble. I only have the compiled Powerbuilder code - I cant find the source code.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @MikeF If you only use the database with this application, you may try setting the compatibility mode for your database back to 100 to match SQL 2008 levels, but ultimately if you want to take advantage of the new features you will have to dredge up that source code from somewhere or see if someone like Appeon can decompile it for you.

Comment: Thanks. I dont think this version of SQL Server (2017) can set the compatibility to 100 - can it?  I will reach out to Appeon. Are there any other?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2017 [does support 100 compatibility](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/glenn/database-compatibility-level-in-sql-server/).

I also checked my own 2017 server and the option is there (make sure you use the 2017 Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio)